# Finding eigenvectors of a $2 \times 2$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For the following matrix,

\begin{bmatrix}1&h\\0&1\end{bmatrix}

I was able to find the eigenvalues to be $1$ with multiplicity $2$. How to find the eigenvectors?

Comment: How would you usually look for eigenvectors?

Comment: by solving the equation (yI-A)v=0,  where y is the eigen value, I is the unit vector, v is the eigen vector  and A is the matrix above

Comment: (I would personally say $Av=yv$. That's more in line with what "eigenvector" means. But it works either way.) What's stopping you this time?

Comment: Thats correct too. \begin{bmatrix}1-y&h\\0&1-y\end{bmatrix} *v, I couldn't solve the equation when substitute y=1

Comment: But if I use the eigen vectors to have the matrix p, the PAP^-1 doesn't give me a digonal matrix

Comment: I wanted to find the eigen vectors in order to get the matrix P that can transform the matrix A into a digonal form

Comment: Okay, thank u so much.

Answer (score 0):

If $h\neq0$, there is only one eigenvector (up to scaling). That's $(1,0)^T$. We must have $y=0$. We can see this from the equation
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&h\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=1\cdot\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}\\
\cases{x+hy=x\\y=y}
$$
This is a common and important phenomenon, and as a consequence there are many ways of expressing it. For instance:

- The *algebraic multiplicity* of the eigenvalue (you got $1$ as a *double* root of the characteristic polynomial) doesn't equal the geometric multiplicity (the eigenspace has dimension *one*)
- Your matrix is not diagonalizable
- Your matrix is defective
- The minimal polynomial of your matrix has a multiple root

Comment: Thank u so much

Answer (score 0):

Using Python + SymPy:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> h = Symbol("h")
>>> A = Matrix([[1, h],
                [0, 1]])
```

Let us try to diagonalize the matrix:

```
>>> A.diagonalize()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sympy/matrices/matrices.py", line 377, in diagonalize
    return _diagonalize(self, reals_only=reals_only, sort=sort,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sympy/matrices/eigen.py", line 605, in _diagonalize
    raise MatrixError("Matrix is not diagonalizable")
sympy.matrices.common.MatrixError: Matrix is not diagonalizable
```

Matrix $A$ is **not** diagonalizable for general $h$, though it is trivially diagonalizable when $h=0$. Thus, let us compute a Jordan decomposition $A =  P J P^{-1}$:

```
>>> P, J = A.jordan_form()
>>> P
Matrix([[h, 0],
        [0, 1]])
>>> J
Matrix([[1, 1],
        [0, 1]])
```